# Spark UI: Executors tab it's empty

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-ui

I'm running the Spark UI on my web server, by exporting the following SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS:

```
export SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="-Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=${LOCAL_PATH_LOGS}
-Dspark.history.ui.port=18080 
-Dspark.eventLog.enabled=true 
-Dspark.ui.proxyRedirectUri=${SERVER_URL}"

./start-history-server.sh
```

The UI runs successfully at the address https://${SERVER_URL}/proxy/18080/.

But if I'm trying to access the Executors tab for one of the applications, it is empty.

By debugging from the browser, I see that the API call `/allexecutors` returns a 404, because the URL is formatted in the wrong way.
Instead of calling `https://${SERVER_URL}/proxy/18080/api/v1/applications/${APP_ID}/allexecutors`
I see that the URL called is `https://${SERVER_URL}/proxy/18080/api/v1/applications/18080/allexecutors`.

I don't know if this can be related to the problem. I was checking in the documentation, but I cannot figure out how to fix this problem. Can you please help me? Thank you!